# Django Many to One / One to Many relationships

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have two models, Book, and Author. Each Author has many books, and each book has many authors, so I set up a ManyToMany relation between Author and Book as the following:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book, related_name='authors')

class Book(models.Model):
    # some fields
```

I have certain alert IDs handy and I need to associate each book object with related authors, so I do (assume I have the id for all these objects handy):

```
author = Author.objects.get(pk=id)
book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
author.books.add(book)
logger.debug(author.book_set.all())
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'author_set'.
```

I am following convention from the django documentation here but it's not seeming to work for me: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Can someone explain why I might be encountering this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the field is

```
class Author:
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book, related_name='authors')
```

You should do

```
logger.debug(author.books.all())
```

The field names with `_set` appended are the defaults for following the relationship the other way, e.g. `book.author_set.all()`. However, you have set a `related` name, so you would use `book.authors.all()` instead,

Comment: Setting the related name to `books` would mean that you would use `book.books.all()` to get the authors for a book. I'm not sure that really makes much sense either.

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm I misread the question before, I've fixed it now.